# Usings Verold's 3ds max exporter - animation not working

Tags: verold

If I export the max project as an .FBX it will work ([HERE](http://www.verold.com/projects/54caa49c20aef934331dcbfa) - the pedal depresses ok), but then I loose turbo smooth (wheel alloys) and line objects (cables) disappear (why is that btw?). Using the Verold exporter, the animation asset appears in the 'key frame animation' tab in the 'choose asset' section, but when applied it never actually animates. And yet, if I animate a simple box next to the pedal, that works ([HERE](http://www.verold.com/projects/54cab77220aef934331dcd9b)).

Partial solution: It seems the problem for Verold was that the pedal's parts were grouped, it works if they are attached instead. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, it sounds like there are three issues:

1. Your TurboSmooth modifier is not being applied when exporting to FBX
2. Your line objects are not rendering
3. Your animation is not playing correctly, when exported by Verold Publisher

To apply TurboSmooth when exporting to FBX, please see the following:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/23085/3ds-max-fbx-turbosmooth-export.html

Note that line objects are not currently supported in Verold Studio, so they will not render.

Regarding animation, when I look at your first example, I see an animated pedal. In your second example, I see an animated box. Should there be additional animated objects in either example?

Comment: Thanks Ian, 

1) The turbo smooth checkbox is clicked on the Geometry tab during .fbx export, so perhaps its a Verold issue? 

2) That's useful info, I will convert them into polys before exporting. 

3) Yes, the second one is supposed to have the pedal animated as well, however I have solved that problem - it was because the pedal's parts were grouped, it works if they are attached instead.

Comment: 1) solved through variation on the link you gave: reset Xform then collapsed object, then converted back to editable poly.